# axes with different scale

Tags: pstricks

Using pstricks and psaxes I'd like to create the axes just like in the attached figure.

I tryed to change Oy, dy and Dy as well as the origin of the axis but  I'm not getting the same as the figure.

I suppose that it is very simple, but how?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\psset{yunit=1.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(5,3)
    \psaxes[arrows=->,showorigin=false,Dy=1.5,dy=2,Oy=0.75,labels=x](0,0.75)(-0.5,0.5)(4.5,2.5)
    \psyTick(1){1}\psyTick(2){2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was struggling with that.